# Return non optional value in getter, while allowing optional value in setter

Tags: swift, setter, getter, option-type

```
class MyClass {
    private var _image: UIImage

    var image: UIImage {
        set {
            if newValue == nil {
                _image = UIImage(named: "some_image")!
            }
        }
        get {
            return _image
        }
    }
}
```

My goal is to guarantee non-optional value when `image` is accessed

Can i achieve this without additional function?

Even if i use `didSet`/`willSet` they are still bound to that `UIImage` type and i can't check for `nil`...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use an implicitly unwrapped optional. Since your getter is just a wrapper for a non optional UIImage you know that your getter will always produce a non nil value (and since `image` is implicitly unwrapped, it will be treated as such), but this will also allow your setter to accept nil values. Perhaps something like this.

```
class MyClass {
    private var _image: UIImage // ...

    var image: UIImage! {
        get {
            return _image
        }

        set {
            if let newValue = newValue {
                _image = newValue
            } else {
                _image = UIImage(named: "some_image")!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where

```
image = nil
```

will assign `_image` your default value, and

```
image = UIImage(named: "something_that_exists")!
```

will assign the new image to `_image`. Note that this also allows you to assign to the variable from `UIImage(named:)` without forcibly unwrapping the optional. If UIImage's initializer fails because it can't find the image, it will evaluate to nil and still cause `_image` to be assigned your default image.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do:

```
private var image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "some_image")!
```

So image is initialized with a default image and this image will be used if you do not set to another one.

```
private var _image: UIImage?

var image: UIImage? {
    set {
        if _image == nil {
            _image = newValue 
        }
    }
    get {
        return _image
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, i guess it won't work... i pretty much want to achieve something like this: set -> UIImage? { } get -> UIImage { } I want to have centarlized initializer so it can be possible to be set nil value without checking if some fetched data for example is nil

Comment: I edit my answer I think this is what you are looking for in this case

Comment: its ok, but if i call myClassObject.image! i will need to unwrap it with '!'... i just want directly to access it like myClassObject.image :D

Comment: You always have to unwrap optionals to use in swift and you cannot have a not optional value with a reference to nil

Comment: So its not possible? i can achieve this with functions, but i guessed it will be possible with in built computed properties... which is kinda odd...

Comment: @JovanMeshkov If you make the type `UIImage!` instead of `UIImage?` you won't have to unwrap it yourself.

Comment: @JovanMeshkov You welcome! But I don't think you are setting image to nil in the example above you are just setting to "someImage"

Comment: Well i will never set it to nil in my private variable, but it is allowed to be set nil through the property, what i exactly wanted to achieve is demonstrated in  @0x7fffffff's answer

Comment: But the property is never set to nil, it is either set to newValue or to UIImage(named: "some_image")! but it is never nil.

Comment: Ah I think now I understand what you want, you don't want to set it to nil, you want to set it to the default pic when you use the nil. Got it! Nice work!

Answer (score 0):

You can make your backing variable (`_image`) optional, so your public property won't be. Use the nil coalescing operator (`??`) to determine which to return.

```
class MyClass {
    private var _image: UIImage?

    var image: UIImage {
        set { _image = newValue }
        get { return _image ?? UIImage(named: "some_image")! }
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't say you wanted to do that in your question.